# Maven dependency management project in eclipse

Tags: maven, dependencies, hamcrest, maven-dependency

While creating a maven project in eclipse,under maven dependencies I got junit3.8.1.jar file but hamcrest-core 1.3.jar file is missing,and it's dependencies are also missing.when my sir was teaching in online he got the hamcrest-core 1.3 jar file and their dependents automatically when he created the maven project
How to get them automatically

While creating a maven project in eclipse,under maven dependencies I got junit3.8.1.jar file but hamcrest-core 1.3.jar file is missing,and it's dependencies are also missing.when my sir was teaching in online he got the hamcrest-core 1.3 jar file and their dependents automatically

Comment: To my experience creating directly a Maven project is a bad idea as it creates a project with outdated defaults like it targets Java 6 or 7. It is better to create a Java project first and configure e.g. Java version and then use Configure from project context menu to convert it to a Maven project (add Maven nature).